# Karpathy Pong cross-entropy/log loss explanation for y - aprob

Tags: python, gradient, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to understand Karpathy's pong code in Python explained here:  [karpathy pong](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/)

```
# forward the policy network and sample an action from the returned probability
  #########action 2 is up and 3 is down
  aprob, h = policy_forward(x)
  print("aprob\n {}\n h\n {}\n".format(aprob, h))
  #2 is up, 3 is down
  action = 2 if np.random.uniform() < aprob else 3 # roll the dice!
  print("action\n {}\n".format(action))
  # record various intermediates (needed later for backprop)
  xs.append(x) # observation, ie. the difference frame?
  #print("xs {}".format(xs))
  hs.append(h) # hidden state obtained from forward pass
  #print("hs {}".format(hs)) 
  #if action is up, y = 1, else 0
  y = 1 if action == 2 else 0 # a "fake label"
  print("y \n{}\n".format(y))
  dlogps.append(y - aprob) # grad that encourages the action that was taken to be taken (see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#losses if confused)
  print("dlogps\n {}\n".format(dlogps))
  # step the environment and get new measurements
  observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
  print("observation\n {}\n reward\n {}\n done\n {}\n ".format(observation, reward, done))
  reward_sum += reward
  print("reward_sum\n {}\n".format(reward_sum))
  drs.append(reward) # record reward (has to be done after we call step() to get reward for previous action)
  print("drs\n {}\n".format(drs))
  if done: # an episode finished
    episode_number += 1
```

In the above snippet, I don't quite understand why a fake label is necessary and what this means:
`dlogps.append(y - aprob)# grad that encourages the action that was taken to be taken (see http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#losses if confused)`

Why is it fake label `y` minus `aprob`?

My understanding is that the network outputs a "log probability" of moving up but then the explanation seems to indicate that the label should actually be the reward obtained for taking that action and then encourage all actions within an episode if it is a winning one.  Thus, I don't understand how a fake label of 1 or 0 helps.

Also in the forward pass function, there is no log operation so how is it a log probability?

```
#forward pass, how is logp a logp without any log operation?????
def policy_forward(x):
  h = np.dot(model['W1'], x)
  h[h<0] = 0 # ReLU nonlinearity
  logp = np.dot(model['W2'], h)
  p = sigmoid(logp)
  #print("p\n {}\n and h\n {}\n".format(p, h))
  return p, h # return probability of taking action 2 (up), and hidden state
```

Edit:

I used print statements to see what's happening under the hood and discovered that since `y=0` for action down, `(y - aprob)` will be negative for action down.  His formula to modulate gradient with advantage `epdlogp *= discounted_epr` still ends up indicating whether a move down was good, ie. a negative number or bad, ie. a positive number.
  And for action up, the reverse is true when formula is applied.  ie. positive number for `epdlogp *= discounted_epr` means action was good, and negative means action was bad.
  So this seems to be a fairly neat way to implement but I still don't understand how `aprob` returned from the forward pass is a log probability since output to console looks like this:

```
aprob
 0.5

action
 3

aprob
 0.5010495775824385

action
 2

aprob
 0.5023498477623756

action
 2

aprob
 0.5051575154468827

action
 2
```

Those look like probabilities between 0 and 1.  So is using `y - aprob` as a "log probability" just a hack that comes with intuition developed over many months and years of practice?  If so, are these hacks discovered by trial and error?

Edit:  Thanks to the great explanation by Tommy, I knew where to look in my Udacity Deep Learning course videos for a refresher on log probabilities and cross entropy:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=94&v=iREoPUrpXvE

Also, this cheatsheet helped:  https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loss_functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*My explanation of how he gets to (y-aprob):*

When he does a forward pass through his net, the last step is applying the sigmoid S(x) to the output of the last neuron.

```
S(x) = 1 / (1+e^-x)
```

and its gradient

```
grad S(x) = S(x)(1-S(X))
```

To increase/decrease the likelihood of your actions you have to calculate log of your probabilities of your 'labels'

```
L = log p(y|x)
```

To backpropagate this you have to calculate the gradient of your likelihood L

```
grad L = grad log p(y|x)
```

Since you applied the sigmoid function p = S(y) on your output you actually calculate

```
grad L = grad log S(y)   
grad L = 1 / S(y) * S(y)(1-(S(y))  
grad L = (1-S(y))  
**grad L = (1-p)**
```

This is actually nothing more than the Log Loss / Cross Entropy. 
A more general formula would be:

```
L = - (y log p + (1-y)log(1-p))  
grad L = y-p with y either 0 or 1
```

Since Andrej is not using frameworks like Tensorflow or PyTorch in his example he did some backpropagation right there.

At the beginning I was quite confused too and it took me some time to figure out what magic is going on there. Maybe he could have been a bit more clear there and give some hints.

At least that is my humble understanding of his code :)

Comment: I had to pour over my old notes regarding cross-entropy, logistic regression and sigmoids but your explanation glued them together.  Andrew Ng's machine learning course on Coursera does a pretty good job explaining the concepts.